# Adding bootstrap & Font awesome ruins css-why?

Tags: html, fonts, font-awesome-3.2

Since I added bootstrap and font awesome to my html file, most of the css done before just disappeared (background-color, google fonts)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Games</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>       
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Homemade+Apple' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

Does someone know why? Thanks!!

Comment: you try to change order?

Answer (score 0):

Move your `main.css` file declaration to *after* your bootstrap and font-awesome declarations. Since CSS is **cascading** the later styles are overwriting your custom styles.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Games</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>       
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Homemade+Apple' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">  
</head>
```

Comment: If the bootstrap css has a higher specificity, changing the order won't help a bit.

Comment: @GolezTrol generally, Bootstrap doesn't use `!important` for precisely this reason.

Comment: I'm not talking about that. I said [Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), which is much more than just adding `!important`. (And you should never use `!important` anyway)

Comment: @GolezTrol I hadn't heard that term, but I get the concept. It could still be overwritten by a later file with the same (or higher) specificity.

Comment: I mean that if the Bootstrapper's specificity is higher, the later file won't overwrite the previous one, so just changing the order is probably not a full solution. Can't hurt to try, of course, maybe you're lucky. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol I agree, custom styles should still be placed after framework styles, however.

Comment: @ Steve Thanks- moving the css after bootstrap worked for the color and the fonts, but now the order of elements got weird- so they are not at the same place they were before.. Its not a big problem since I can just change margins etc, but just wonder what the reason is!